# ASP.net core signalr angular client, error "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check"

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

So I have this code in ASP.Net core server startup.cs in ConfigureServices method :

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
            builder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44345");
        }));
```

And within Configure method :

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

In angular I have this :

```
  ngOnInit(): void
```

{

```
this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('https://localhost:44305/hub').build();
this._hubConnection
  .start()
  .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));
```

}

The client part and server part will run on different domains, they are 2 separate projects in visual Studio.

Anyway when running the angular code i get this error :

```
Failed to load https://localhost:44305/hub/negotiate: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'https://localhost:44345' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

So I guess I have 2 options, either get the client side code to pass false for the withCredentials attribute or somehow change the server side code do it sends a Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header set to true.
The problem is I don't know how to do either of those things, I can't find a setting for withCredentials anywhere.

Comment: You are allowing port 44345 but using port 44305?

Comment: Port 44305 is for the server part and port 44345 is for the client part. CORS allows the client 44345 and the client connects to the server url 44305

Comment: Oops my bad. Anyways it can depend on where you use the `app.UseCors` in the ASP.NET pipeline, it needs to come before authentication for example

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it, i needed to include .AllowCredentials()   in the services.addCors part.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, This solved it for me. I really did not expect that allowing credentials should make the difference between sending true or an empty string... better start reading more on asp coors management